# Azure DevOps is not notifying changes to Comments

Tags: azure-devops

Created Notification subscription for changes to the Comments field, both changes to and changes in count of.  But the emails are not getting delivered.

This was done at the Project settings level.  Notifications for other fields, setup the same way work, so changes to Description field gets delivered.  It's only the Comments field- actually this is the Discussion section of the User Story.  Which are composed of multiple Comments.

PS: the subscription is enabled- both at project level and individual level.  I unchecked the "Skip Initiator" so can test.  Tried both Members of Team by Role option and just Members of Team.  Filter is set simply to Comments, Changes.  For the other subscription it's Comments Count, Changes...

Should there be some other settings elsewhere which is affecting notification for only this field?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Comments on a work item are surface through the "History" field. You can change your subscription to point to that field and try again.I convinced this will work.
[image]

Comment: Thank you Hugh, after ~2h of digging I finally found your post. You are a life saver :D